# "Ubered everywhere" meaning

Tags: verbs, word-usage, slang, proper-nouns

On *Modern Family* episode 1 of season 7, Michael says to Cameron

> Oh, you walked over here. I just thought you Uber-ed everywhere.

I know what [Uber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uber_(company)) is, but I can't understand *ubered everywhere* meaning in this sentence. He said that while Cameron come toward him from the other side of the table.

Comment: Do you not know what Uber is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uber_(company) ?

Comment: i know what Uber is, but i cant understand 'ubered everywhere' meaning in this sentense! he said that while cameron come near him from the other side of the table!

Comment: Look up [verbification of nouns](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=verbification+of+nouns&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=f4adWeLeK_Pk8AfOqpSoBg&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Related: [über alles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCber_alles) and [semper ubi sub ubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Latin).

Comment: I haven't seen that episode recently, but could it be that it's _Mitchell_ (Cameron's husband) who says that rather than _Michael_ (not sure if there even is a Michael on the show)?

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned being aware of Uber as a company, so I'll forgo explaining that part. Michael's statement is basically the same as saying:

> "Oh, I thought you'd take a taxi to get to the other side of the table, since you always take a taxi, even for ridiculously short trips".

Michael's phrasing is wittier than mine, but the meaning is the same.

It's hyperbole, exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally.